# Is it possible to return all Key-Value Pairs from an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I currently have an object which has a number of dynamically created attributes/keys, which looks like the following:

```
   #<Employee _id: 54af214d6175720da8130000, name: "Barry", company: ["Google", "Microsoft", "HP"], customFieldName: "ABC">
```

In order to fulfill my project's requirements, I need to be able to iterate through each element of this object, and print the Key:Value pairs. i.e.

```
Name: Barry

Company:

 1. Google
 2. Microsoft
 3. HP

customFieldName: ABC
```

I've had a look around online (and found an article on reflection (which is what I would do in C#), which doesn't appear to be what I'm looking for. :/), but I can't work out how to do this.

A simple `@employeeObj.each` loop doesn't help, either. :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks heaps in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to call `@employee.attributes` which will return a hash and then you can loop over the key values as so:

```
@employee.attributes.each do |key, value|

end
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I wanted. Thanks heaps! :)